# Extract a value from an document in array matching a condition in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following document in mongoDb

```
{'_id':
  {'$oid': '5e201825ab6aae4908582cd6'},
  'users':[{'_id':{'$oid':'5e201825ab6aae4908582cda'},
          'username':'AndreyTrz',
          'email':'*********@gmail.com',
          'name':'Andrey'},
        {'_id':{'$oid':'5e201825ab6aae4908582cd9'},
        'email':'bot2@mail.com',
        'username':'bot2',
        'name':'user 2'},
        {'_id':{'$oid':'5e201825ab6aae4908582cd8'},
        'email':'bot1@mail.com',
        'username':'bot1',
        'name':'user 1'},
        {'_id':{'$oid':'5e201825ab6aae4908582cd7'},
        'email':'bot3@mail.com',
        'username':'bot3',
        'name':'user 3'}],
  'draftMessages':[],
  'messages':[{'unread':['bot2','bot3'],
              '_id':{'$oid':'5e205b4a5c7cd5577019253d'},
              'chatID':'5e201825ab6aae4908582cd6',
              'text':'ghjghfjk gfhdgfhdgfh dgfh dfgh',
              'date':{'$numberDouble':'1579178826679'},
              'edited':false,
              'authorId':'bot1'},

              {'unread':['bot2','bot3'],
              '_id':{'$oid':'5e205577397c4c57e408fc0b'},
              'chatID':'5e201825ab6aae4908582cd6',
              'text':'qwerty',
              'date':{'$numberDouble':'1579177335719'},
              'edited':false,
              'authorId':'bot1'},

              {'unread':['bot2','bot1','bot3'],
              '_id':{'$oid':'5e2053e3397c4c57e408fbf6'},
              'chatID':'5e201825ab6aae4908582cd6',
              'text':'Hello',
              'date':{'$numberDouble':'1579176931640'},
              'edited':false,
              'authorId':'AndreyTrz'}],
'type':{'$numberInt':'2'},
'chatName':'Group Chat',
'admin':'AndreyTrz',
'__v':{'$numberInt':'0'}}
```

I want to extract subdocuments from 'messages', which have in 'unread' 'bot2'. I am using such query

```
collection.aggregate([
          {$match: {'_id' : new ObjectId('5e201825ab6aae4908582cd6')},
          {$project:
            {query:
              {$filter:
                {input: `messages`,
                as: 'item',
                cond: {
                 $eq: [`$$item.unread`, ['bot2']
                }
                }
              }
            }
          }]
```

It works only when 'unread: ['bot2']'. When I have something like that unread: ['bo2', 'bot3'] it does not work. How should I change my query to MongoDb to get cover case when I have another values in array?

Comment: Try the aggregation [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator like this `$in: [ "bot2", "$$item.unread" ]` in place of `$eq: [`$$item.unread`, ['bot2']`.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I was stuck with this problem and you helped me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like

```
$eq: [`$$item.unread`, 'bot2']
```

Because, if you want to match value being in array, you don't have to provide square brackets

If you provide square brackets, it will match the exact array, that won't solve your purpose